# Laravel my post method (store) form not working

Tags: php, laravel, forms, redirect, store

### PostsController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
 Post::create($request->all());
 return redirect('/posts');
}
```

### my view create.blade.php in posts directory

```
@extends('layout.app')



@section('content')

    <h1>Create Post</h1>

    <form action="/posts" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter title"> <!-- this name=title comes from create_posts_table -->
        {{--{{csrf_field()}}--}}
        <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>

@stop
```

### Route

```
Route::resource('/posts','PostsController');
```

when I submit browser goes to localhost/posts and it says:

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.5
```

---

and no record wont save

Comment: Did you set the document root to `/public`?

Comment: Is this the only route that has this problem?

Comment: @ChinLeung /posts/

Comment: @Nima yes and update is wont works too

Comment: I think @ChinLeung means is your Apache or web server DocumentRoot set to the /public folder inside your Laravel source?

Comment: @RoboBear I use xampp
and this is my url:
localhost/www/laravelcms/public/

Comment: I think my problem comes from my localhost and xampp
I need correct configuration of route or localhost url or I don't know what

Comment: my url is:
localhost/www/laravelcms/public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="post">
    //
</form>
```

or you can read [this document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) for more information. and take note you CAN NOT send post request by browser calling url. you can submit a form for it

Comment: I tried this and url fixed but this message comes:

The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.

Comment: I think you should check csrf field  

Comment: Send a user_id to store. Or make it nullable in migration

Comment: many Thanks Ehsan
and one more question: How can I change this url action:
<form action="/posts/{{$post->id}}"
it's for edit form page


to somthing like that you sent:
<form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}"

Comment: You can pass data to it like : {{ route(‘posts.store’, [‘id’ => $post->id] }}

Comment: Maybe ‘id’ should be replaced by ‘post’ in data

Comment: thanks I change my action and it is working now:
{{ route('posts.update',['id' => $post->id ]) }}

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with this.

You're using a resource route so you need to route appropriately to the store method:

```
 <form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="post">
```

Also, you need to spoof methods on your other controller endpoints such as the DELETE method as it will fail with a POST request you can do that like so:

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.delete') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

Take a look here I cover just that on this video https://youtu.be/kPYtJo7RyUQ